# Force an instance of class to use an interface

Tags: c#, oop

How do I force `WebSocketClient`'s class instance to use the `IWebSocketClient` interface in its instantiation?

For ex. I don't have `ConnectAsync` method listed in the interface and I expect the code to not allow me to call it.

```cs
IWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri);
await webSocketClient
    .ConnectAsync(CancellationToken.None) // ConnectAsync is missing which is expected behavior
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

```cs
var webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri);
await webSocketClient
    .ConnectAsync(CancellationToken.None) // it allows me to call it, which is not expected behavior
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

### Snippet

```cs
public interface IWebSocketClient : IDisposable
{
    WebSocketState State { get; }
}

public class WebSocketClient : IWebSocketClient
{
    public WebSocketClient(Uri uri)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public WebSocketState State => _webSocket.State;

    public async Task ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not expose a public constructor, but instead a factory method. (For that matter, if you do not want code to call a public function, why is it public? Should it exist somewhere else?)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, good idea. I also remember that I could do explicit interface implementation `async Task IWebSocketClient.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`, which encourages people to use the interface.

Comment: Yes, explicit implementation works for that method if it is declared by an interface, but you've left it out of your interface definition presumably intentionally. But if your intent is for that method to in fact be visible only via the interface, explicit is the way to go.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, I like the factory method as well. Do you suggest `public static IWebSocketClient Create(Uri uri) => new WebSocketClient(uri);` and to make the constructor `internal`?

Comment: If the constructor is internal, then any class within the assembly can invoke it, so if you're intending to use that class within the same assembly (and do not want direct construction), it should be more restricted. Start with private (meaning the class exposes its own factory method) and work up from there.

Comment: But in the first code snippet all we need to do is cast if we want to call it.. ? "Absent from an intellisense popup" and "actually impossible to call externally" are two different things

Answer (score -2):

Make a base class that is abstract, then implement the interface as abstract methods. This will force all subclasses to implement those methods.

Edit: Rereading your question has me wondering if I've misunderstood your problem. If you want an IWebSocketClient to always have a ConnectAsync method, then you just add that method to the interface. Right now the interface only has the State, not the ConnectAsync method.

If alternatively, you don't want any other code to be able to call ConnectAync, then you need to make it private.